# Texifier HTTP response failure

Tags: errors

For mobility reasons I have to use my IPad for Latex and have used Texifier for two years, which was always more than fine and comfortable.

Since yesterday I have been getting the following error when trying to compile:

HTTP response failure: ERROR domain=NSURLErrorDomainCode=-1004 „Verbindung zum Server konnte nicht hergestellt werden“.

Does anyone here know of any changes they have made or server problems or fixes?

THE LOG:

```
**[OPEN] Item added to currently open projects: [icloud]/com~apple~CloudDocs/Material/2023/EAutohersteller.tex
Typeset request failed with error: HTTP response failure: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Verbindung zum Server konnte nicht hergestellt werden." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x28158c2a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, dns, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <A11825C9-E700-4CC5-A90E-BEC161CE750A>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <A11825C9-E700-4CC5-A90E-BEC161CE750A>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Verbindung zum Server konnte nicht hergestellt werden., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://typeset.texpadapp.com/api/5/typeset, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://typeset.texpadapp.com/api/5/typeset, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
Failed to find Connect file system.
**[CLOSE] Closing project for item: [icloud]/com~apple~CloudDocs/Material/2023/EAutohersteller.tex
**[OPEN] Item added to currently open projects: [icloud]/com~apple~CloudDocs/texpad-error-log.txt
**[CLOSE] Closing project for item: [icloud]/com~apple~CloudDocs/texpad-error-log.txt
[TPWorkspaceController restoreEditorState:] nil document!
**[OPEN] Item added to currently open projects: [icloud]/com~apple~CloudDocs/Material/2023/EAutohersteller.tex
Typeset request failed with error: HTTP response failure: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Verbindung zum Server konnte nicht hergestellt werden." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x2815266d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, dns, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <064C6D07-2446-479C-9491-BF89BB889881>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <064C6D07-2446-479C-9491-BF89BB889881>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Verbindung zum Server konnte nicht hergestellt werden., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://typeset.texpadapp.com/api/5/typeset, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://typeset.texpadapp.com/api/5/typeset, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
Failed to find Connect file system.
**[CLOSE] Closing project for item: [icloud]/com~apple~CloudDocs/Material/2023/EAutohersteller.tex
```

MY HEADER:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage[ngerman,german]{babel}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{setspace}
```

Comment: the error you show is an http connection error so can not be related to the document code you show. It's a local network issue, someone may recognise it and help (sorry I don't have that setup) but it's not really on topic here and not connected to the document you posted.

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your response! Sorry that I have so little knowledge that I can‘t even post anywhere on topic or ask in the right manner. It does not appear that I have any network errors here, but maybe something changed and I need to grant any new permissions in order for the compiler to access crucial data, which I did not need to grant in the past?? Maybe someone has an idea.

Comment: Your German message is `Connection to the server could not be established.`  so your machine could not connect to the texify server so presumably you could replace all the code you have shown by a document that just said `oops` and would get exactly the same. Your document is not even being looked at as your machine can not connect to the server. So either your firewall is blocking it, or the server is down today, or a man with a spade cut your internet cable or ... it could be anything but it is not a tex error.

Comment: I actually get the same error since monday... I already wrote them, but up to now no answer unfortunately. I like texifier really but the support is a little bit weak and u even find no news

Comment: Hi, I’m a longtime user of Texifier and beginning a couple days ago I began receiving the same error. In English it is ‘Typeset request failed with error: HTTP response failure: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."’ I’ve also emailed them with no response so far. I thought it was an issue with my network but I tried on several different networks with the same error. Seeing your post here confirms that the problem lies with Texifier. If you would please let me know if you get a response from them, I will gladly do the same.

Comment: The server should be online again.